# Should I have not deleted my answer?

Tags: discussion

In the question [Is anyone concerned about Daenerys' lack of an heir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/is-anyone-concerned-about-daenerys-lack-of-an-heir), I had posted an answer. Upon further comments from the OP, I realized his question is primarily going to be opinion based. I deleted my answer and voted to close. Should I have left my answer up? Should I undelete it?

Comment: Meh. It's all the same since the question is on its way to being closed

Comment: Do you mean from an ethical standpoint (e.g. That you didn't want to answer it *and* vote to close it)?

Answer (score 3):

### No, there's no need for you to undelete it.

Because **it doesn't really answer the question**, as stated by the question poster in a comment on your answer before you deleted it.

The question:

> Daenerys is kind of without an heir. Why does no one in the show seem concerned about this after season 1? [...] In the books how and when is concern over this brought up? What are proposed resolutions if any?

Your answer:

[image: screenshot of deleted answer]

Most of this answer is talking about who else might or might not be ahead of Dany in the line of succession, rather than about the issue of Daenerys not having a child. The one part that isn't (point 1) is about Dany's *barrenness*, which still isn't quite the same issue. Sure, nobody knows she's barren, but everyone knows she doesn't actually have a child.

**None of this answers the question of why people don't see Dany's childlessness as an issue.** Even if Jon and/or Tyrion are ahead of Dany in the Targaryen line of succession, nobody knows about it; nor does anybody know about her barrenness; so these are all irrelevant to the main question.